# How to save matrices into a larger matrix one at a time?

Tags: r, matrix, saving-data

This is being done in R.

Say you have a loop the is producing matrixs each interation.

You have results like this

```
1  10 3 4 5 6
2  8  2 4 5 1
3  11 9 0 0 NA
4  2  3 4 5 6 
5  7  8 9 3 2
```

The matrix being produced is always of the same dimensions, in this example nrow=5, ncol=5.
Say I'm creating 25 of these matrices and would like them saved in one large matrix of dimensions nrow=125, ncol=5. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance and let me know if you need anything clarified,
Nick

Comment: Create a `list` object and save the matrices in the `list` i.e. `lst <- vector('list', 25); for(i in 1:25){lst[[i]] <- your calculation}; do.call(rbind, lst)`

Comment: What @akrun said, except if you have a lot of matrices to `rbind` then `rbindlist` will be faster than `do.call(rbind, lst)`

Comment: @mrip Just to add, `rbindlist` needs a list of `data.frames`, so it should be converted to `data.frame` before doing it.

Comment: @akrun Thanks, I didn't know that.  Guess that makes sense since it's part of `data.table`, which I had forgotten because I always import it.